# Value range of the probability of three events

Tags: probability

Given 3 events A,B,C which have the same probability of 0.75
I need to prove that P(A & B & C) is between 0.25 and 0.75
I kind of stuck in proving the lower bound
I assume that I need to use the Inclusion-Exlusion principle but I haven't reached the correct answer

Comment: BTW, this is an example of the [Frechet inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inequalities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See probability of $A,B,C$ are $0.75$ so $P(A$ & $  B$ & $  C)\leq 0.75$ is clear right?

Again, probability of $A^c,B^c,C^c$ are $0.25$ so $P(A^c$ OR $  B^c$ OR $  C^c)\leq 0.75$. Hence, by taking complement $P(A$ & $B$ & $C)\geq0.25$. Is that clear?

***EDIT***

See, Probability of $A^c,B^c,C^c$ are $0.25$ so $P(A^c$ OR $  B^c$ OR $  C^c)\leq 0.75$ is clear right?

Next using De Morgan's law, we have $P(A^c$ OR $  B^c$ OR $  C^c)=P((A$ & $B$ & $C)^c)$

So, $P((A$ & $B$ & $C)^c)\leq0.75\implies 1-P((A$ & $B$ & $C)^c)\geq1-0.75$

$\implies P(A$ & $B$ & $C)\geq0.25$

Now it is clear right??

Comment: Thanks, I feel a little stupid that I missed it

Comment: Its ok...where do you study?

Comment: Hebrew university in Israel

Comment: After reviewing your answer , I found a flaw: the complement of $P(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c)$ according to the De Morgan's laws is $P(A \cup B \cup C)$, so the only new information I received is that $P(A \cup B \cup C)\geq 0.75$

Comment: Ok, I explained it more thoroughly now.